# Need to know why Method Range of Object Worksheet Failed Error is occuring

Tags: vba, excel

**The idea of the code below is to look up a few tables, match headers from two different tables and move the answers from one table to the next.**

The Method Range of Object Worksheet Failed is happening on the Find function:

`@ colForAnswer = ws.Range(rngColLookup).Find(curCell, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column.`

I have searched all over and cannot find any solutions that solve this problem. Can someone please help me understand why it is not working.

Thank you!

```
Sub submitResponses()

'find question name, Grab answer column of table by row, match up to question column, place answer
'view scoring functions if needed

'Redefine a named range of the column headers and search that

Dim rngHeaders As Range
Dim rngAppQ As Range, rngAppQ2 As Range, rngColLookup As Range
Dim rngAppAnswer As Range, rngAppAnswer2 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim answerArea As Integer
Dim colForAnswer As Integer
Dim curCell As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(appSheet)

Set rngAppQ = Worksheets(aTable).Range("tAppInfo" & "[[#All],[Questions]]")
Set rngAppAnswer = Worksheets(aTable).Range("tAppInfo" & "[[#All],[Answers]]")
Set rngAppQ2 = Worksheets(aTable).Range("tAppInfo2" & "[[#Headers]]")
Set rngAppAnswer2 = Worksheets(aTable).Range("tAppInfo2")
Set rngColLookup = Worksheets(appSheet).Range(appTable & "[[#Headers]]")

Debug.Print rngColLookup.Address

answerArea = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

For Each curCell In rngAppQ

Debug.Print curCell
Debug.Print rngColLookup.Address

colForAnswer = ws.Range(rngColLookup).Find(curCell, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
ws.Cells(answerArea, colForAnswer).Value = curCell

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `ws.Range(rngColLookup)...` to `rngColLookup...` The worksheet and range are already part of the range variable.  The double syntax throws an error.

Comment: Hi, Scott. I had tried that earlier. When I change it to just the range variable, then I get an 'object variable or with variable not set' error

Comment: Scott, I was able to figure out the second issue. Thank you for your suggestion and help!